# How to merge this 2 pine scripts?

Tags: pine-script

can you please help me to merge/combine these two codes into a single script if it's possible? when i tried several merging attempt it gave some undeclared identifier error or this line below

Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Script could not be translated from: |B|float top = na|E|

as far as i can see none of the identifiers interfere but still printing out error

this first code below is already a merge of 2 different codes;

```
study("SUPERTrend Lines", overlay=true)
lb = input(30, title="Left Bars", minval=1)
rb = input(30, title="Right Bars", minval=1)
showpivot = input(true, title="Show Pivot Points")
chdashed = input(true, title="Show Old Line as Dashed")

mb = lb + rb + 1

float top = na
float bot = na
top := iff(not na(high[mb]), iff(highestbars(high, mb) == -rb, high[rb], na), na)  // Pivot High
bot := iff(not na(low[mb]), iff(lowestbars(low, mb) == -rb, low[rb], na), na)  // Pivot Low

plotshape(top and showpivot, text="[PH]",  style=shape.labeldown, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, location=location.abovebar, transp=0, offset = -rb)
plotshape(bot and showpivot, text="[PL]",  style=shape.labeldown, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, location=location.belowbar, transp=0, offset = -rb)

ltop = valuewhen(top, top, 1)
bst = 0
bst := top ? 1 : nz(bst[1]) + 1
float t_angle = 0.0
t_angle := t_angle[1]
if not na(ltop) and not na(top)
    line tline = na
    if ltop > top
        tline := line.new(bar_index - bst[1] - rb, high[bst[1] + rb], bar_index - rb, high[rb], color = color.red, extend = extend.right)
        t_angle := (high[bst[1] + rb] - high[rb]) / bst[1]
        if t_angle < t_angle[1] and t_angle[1] != 0
            line.set_extend(tline[1], extend = extend.none)
        if t_angle > t_angle[1] and t_angle[1] != 0
            line.set_extend(tline, extend = extend.none)
    if ltop <= top
        t_angle := 0.0
    if chdashed
        line.set_style(tline[1], style = line.style_dashed)

lbot = valuewhen(bot, bot, 1)
bsb = 0
bsb := bot ? 1 : nz(bsb[1]) + 1
float b_angle = 0.0
b_angle := b_angle[1]
if not na(lbot) and not na(bot)
    line bline = na
    if lbot < bot
        bline := line.new(bar_index - bsb[1] - rb, low[bsb[1] + rb], bar_index - rb, low[rb], color = color.blue, extend = extend.right)
        b_angle := (low[bsb[1] + rb] - low[rb]) / bsb[1]
        if b_angle > b_angle[1] and b_angle[1] != 0
            line.set_extend(bline[1], extend = extend.none)
        if b_angle < b_angle[1] and b_angle[1] != 0
            line.set_extend(bline, extend = extend.none)
    if lbot >= bot
        b_angle := 0.0
    if chdashed
        line.set_style(bline[1], style = line.style_dashed)


//auto higher time frame
HTF = timeframe.period == '1' ? '5' : 
  timeframe.period == '3' ? '15' : 
  timeframe.period == '5' ? '15' : 
  timeframe.period == '15' ? '60' : 
  timeframe.period == '30' ? '60' : 
  timeframe.period == '45' ? '60' : 
  timeframe.period == '60' ? '240' : 
  timeframe.period == '120' ? '240' : 
  timeframe.period == '180' ? '240' : 
  timeframe.period == '240' ? 'D' : 
  timeframe.period == 'D' ? 'W' :
  '5W'

Mult = input(1.7, minval = 0, maxval = 10)
Period = input(10, minval = 1, maxval = 100)
chbarcol = input(true, title = "Change Bar Color")

[Trailings, Trend] = supertrend(Mult, Period)

linecolor = Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? color.lime :
   Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? color.red :
   color.new(color.white, 100)
plot(Trailings, color = linecolor,  linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend")

[TrailingslHtf, TrendHtf] = security(syminfo.tickerid, HTF, supertrend(Mult, Period), lookahead = true)

linecolorHtf = TrendHtf == -1 and TrendHtf[1] == -1 ? color.blue :
   TrendHtf == 1 and TrendHtf[1] == 1 ? color.red :
   color.new(color.white, 100)
plot(TrailingslHtf, color = linecolorHtf, linewidth = 3, title = "Supertrend Higher Time Frame")

barcolor_ = Trend == -1 and TrendHtf == -1 ? color.lime :
   Trend == 1 and TrendHtf == 1 ? color.red :
   color.white
barcolor(color = chbarcol ? barcolor_ : na)

plotarrow(TrendHtf == -1 and TrendHtf[1] == 1 ? 1 : 0, title="Buy Signal", colorup = color.blue, maxheight = 40, minheight = 30, transp=0)
plotarrow(TrendHtf == 1 and TrendHtf[1] == -1 ? -1 : 0, title="Sell Signal", colordown = color.red, maxheight = 40, minheight = 30, transp=0)

alertcondition(TrendHtf == -1 and TrendHtf[1] == 1, title='Supertrend Buy Signal', message='Supertrend Buy Signal')
alertcondition(TrendHtf == 1 and TrendHtf[1] == -1, title='Supertrend Sell Signal', message='Supertrend Sell Signal')
```

and here's the second script to merge the one above;

```
study("Coral Trend Indicator [LazyBear] Buy-Sell with Alarm by coinsspor", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
i2 = c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
i3 = c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
i4 = c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
i5 = c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
i6 = c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])

bfr = -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For the Pinescript coders: Determining trend based on the mintick step. 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//bfrC = bfr - nz(bfr[1]) > syminfo.mintick ? green : bfr - nz(bfr[1]) < syminfo.mintick ? red : blue
bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? green : bfr < nz(bfr[1])  ? red : blue
tc=ebc?gray:bfrC
plot(ribm?na:bfr, title="Trend", linewidth=3, style=circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc?bfrC:na)
KDbuy=bfr > nz(bfr[1])
KDsell= bfr < nz(bfr[1])
//last_signal= 0
long_final  = KDbuy  and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1)
short_final = KDsell and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == 1)
alertcondition(long_final, title="BUY ALARM", message="Coral Trend Buy Alarm!!!")
alertcondition(short_final, title="SELL ALARM", message="Coral Trend Sell Alarm!!!")

bgcolor( (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1) ? green : red, transp=93)

bgcolor( long_final? green : na, transp=93)
bgcolor( short_final? red : na, transp=93)



last_signal= long_final ? 1 : short_final ? -1 : last_signal[1]



plotshape(long_final, style=shape.labelup,
          location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy label",text="BUY",textcolor=white)
plotshape(short_final, style=shape.labeldown,
          location=location.abovebar, color=red,size=size.tiny,title="sell label",text="SELL",textcolor=white)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The first script is `v4` and the second one is `v2`.

First update the second one to `v3` using [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html) guideline.

After that, you can either update to `v4` yourself using the same guideline or just use the converter.